# save object in session inside a custom spring security filter

Tags: jsf-2, spring-security, session-variables

I am using Spring 3.1.0.RC3 and JSF 2.0.

I implemented a custom spring security filter and I want to store an object in the user session in order to recover it later. Here is how I do it.

```
public class SpringCustomSecurityFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter 
{
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException,
            IOException, ServletException 
    {
        // Putting the attribute
        request.getSession().setAttribute("OBJECT_STRING","hola");

        // Recovering the attribute
        String aux = request.getSession().getAttribute("OBJECT_STRING");
    }

}
```

The problem is that it actually put the object in session but after when I enter into the filter again the attribute doesn't exist in session. So how can I store attribute in session with a JSF front end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should work, have you checked if your session is the same? You can call

```
request.getSession().getId()
```

to verify it.

Comment: Hi you were right, it was working.
The problem was that inside the filter I was calling other site to return me a value inside a callback, so I was executing with the url localhost:8080 and the callback was with the url 127.0.0.1 so the session ID was different. 
Thanks !!!